# how to extract arbitrary amount of bytes from the beginning of a big file?

Tags: files, filemanager, vi

We can truncate a big file to a size we want.  For example, if I want to truncate a file to 1K byte, we can do `truncate -s 1K file1`. But this changes the original file file1.
Many times I want to see a beginning part of a big binary file. To open it with vi and then converting to hex-ascii format (using !%xxd in vi) takes too long. Of course I can copy the original file into another one and truncate the new file and open it with vi.  But is there any way I can just extract from the beginning of a file an amount of bytes I want into another file so that I can open the smaller file to examine the beginning data of the original file?

Comment: Instead of opening the file in `vi` and **then** executing `xxd` on it, why not execute `xxd` with the `-l` option to specify how many bytes of the file you want to examine (and pipe **that** to `vi` if you wish, ex `xxd -l 1024 | vi -`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` can do the trick as in:

```
head -c 1000 bigfile
```

would display the first 1000 bytes.

A construct as

```
head -c 1000 bigfile | vi -
```

would open this in `vi`.

Comment: Thanks, I asked for how to cut file but this is better for my purpose.

Comment: It cuts the file if you redirect the output to a new file rather than to the screen. But as I understood your goal, I immediately indicated the most convenient way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dd`:

```
dd if=big_file of=smaller_file bs=1k count=1
```

Comment: thanks! this one is also good, but I think I'll use `head ... | vi ..` way more often.